# Centering an <hgroup> vertically

Tags: css, html

This is driving me nuts and it's probably painfully easy, how can I float an `<hgroup>` vertically as to center it with the height of a small amount of dynamic content justified to the right (height unknown).

```
<style>
#branding hgroup {
    margin: auto 0 auto 0;
    float:left;
}
#header-contact-info{
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;   
}
</style>

<header id="branding" role="banner">
  <hgroup> 
    <a href="http://thesite.com/"/><img src="logo.png" /></a> 
  </hgroup>
  <div id="header-contact-info">
               <p>some</p>
       <p>contact info</p>
    <p>justified right</p>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</header>
```

So if I have a logo.png that I want centered vertically with the contact info to the right, what CSS styles should I implement?

Comment: That's really not a valid use of `hgroup`, [Permitted contents: one or more of `h1` - `h6`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/hgroup.html#hgroup-content-model)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `hgroup` tag correctly.  It is supposed to contain a group of heading tags such as `h1`, `h2`, etc.

Aside from that, anyone reading this should not use the `<hgroup>` tag anymore because it has been taken out of the HTML5 specification, [as of today](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-hgroup-element-dropped/).